# Defining a whole column as a range in COUNTIFS function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I was wondering if someone could help me with a formula. I have a spreadsheet with two worksheets, the first being called "Datasheet". In the second worksheet, I want to be able to select all of column A in the "Datasheet" worksheet and use a COUNTIFS function to return all values that have the text specified in D4 (which changes; you can select D4's value from a list) that have a specific numerical value (in this case, "2"). I achieved this okay with the formula below:

```
=COUNTIFS(Datasheet!A6:Datasheet!A500, D4, Datasheet!C6:Datasheet!C500, 2)
```

However, I find specifying the A6-A500 / C6-C500 ranges clunky and would prefer to capture the entire columns, to future-proof the formula / spreadsheet for when the number of entries in the database exceeds 500. I tried the following, which produced an error:

```
=COUNTIFS(Datasheet!A:A, D4, Datasheet!E:Datasheet!E, 2)
```

Any ideas on what might work?

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(Datasheet!A:A, D4, Datasheet!E:E, 2)`. You cannot stecify the range where left-top and right-bottom are posessed on different worksheets, so the endpoint of range must NOT be worksheet-specified.

Comment: What error message did you receive? I've been able to create a quick test which worked using both fully columns A:A and naming assign names to columns.

Comment: Thanks guys. @BradR, it is a #VALUE! error. It's Excel 2007; maybe that's why it doesn't accept the ranges, as per Akina's explanation? If you're on 365 maybe it's added that functionality?

Comment: I'm running 2013 here. As you suggested it is probably a versioning issue.